# Implementing strategy design pattern in my dotnet project

Tags: c#

I am working on a coded ui project. I need to implement strategy design pattern in the framework. Please suggest me the right way to implement this design pattern.

The solution is created for multiple states like Colorado, Northdakota, Arizona etc., each state as one project.
There exists Login function which is common to all states, but input varies based on state name.
Likewise there are other functions which are common to all states but varies based on inputs.

These common functions are maintained in a generic functions project.
In Generic functions project, I have created multiple uimaps. LoginUiMap, ProductSearchUiMap, DataEntryUiMap etc.
I have created a class file to store testmethods for the above uimaps like

```
public void LoginUi()
{ 
  this.Login_All.DblClickShortcut();
  this.Login_All.SelectState(statename);
  this.Login_All.ClickOk();
}

public void ProductSearchUi()
{
  this.ProdSearch.ClickProdSearchLink();
  this.ProdSearch.EnterDate();
  this.ProdSearch.EnterId();
  this.ProdSearch.ClickSearch();
}


public void DataEntryUi()
{.....}
```

Then i am calling these methods in each state project in a coded ui test file using [TestMethod] declaration like

1. Arizona state

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public void RunallTests()
   {
     statename = "Arizona";   //based on statename the login function works.

     LoginUi();
     ProdSearch();
     DataEntry();
   }
   ```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm have no experience with codedUI, but your test lacks a lot in terms of testing patterns and verification of expected behaviour or state.